# Java SimpleDateFormat transform into wrong Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

this is maybe a simple question. I am Using SimpleDateFormat to transform a String into a date. I searched through the internet to solve my problem, but i didn't find anything.
But the transformation is wrong. I don't know why.

I want to get the format for example 2015.09.30

This is the Code

```
        Date date1 = null;

        String sd ="2015.09.30";
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
            date1 = sdToDate.parse(sd);
        } catch (ParseException ex2) {
            ex2.printStackTrace();

        }
```

When i know output date1, I get this:
Wed Sep 30 00:00:00 CEST 2015

I hope someone can help me. It's maybe a simple question but i don't get it.

Comment: how are you outputting `date1` ?

Comment: 30.9.2015 gets transformed to 30 september 2015? why is that wrong?

Comment: because i want the format yyyy.MM.dd -> 2015.09.30  as output. 
and outputting with System.out.println

Comment: Use format method of the same SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: If you want that output you'll have to use `sdToDate.format(date1);` and print the result!

Comment: Thank you thats it  -.- i knew it is simple.'
But the problem is, that is use this for a sql query. the output was just a test. And the Date Format in the Database ist yyyy.MM.dd and when i execute the query i get a format error thats why.

Comment: you could use setDate on the preparedStatement instead of setString. If you start with a Date you don't have to convert it to a String first.

Answer (score 2):

When you print date1 as e.g.:

```
System.out.println(date1);
```

Java uses [`Date::toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) function - so you print date in default format.
If you want to print it in different you need to use formatter, e.g.:

```
System.out.println(sdToDate.format(date1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Joanna Kotuła](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065966/642706)  is correct, but uses old classes. We now have a better alternative.

## java.time

You are using outmoded classes. In Java 8 and later use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

The new classes include a class for date-only values, without time-of-day nor time zone: [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

### Standard Format

Your input strings are in a format close to that used by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, but the standard uses a HYPHEN rather than a FULL STOP, `year-month-day`. The standard formats are used java.time classes by default for parsing and generating textual representations of date-time values. So if I were you I would simply [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) the characters, and avoid bothering to define a custom parsing format.

```
String input = "2015.09.30".replace( "." , "-" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input );
```

### Custom Format

The [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) method on `LocalDate` automatically uses the standard ISO 8601 format of `uuuu-MM-dd`.

If you want to generate output strings in your own format, you will need to define a custom format pattern. Use the [java.time.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu.MM.dd" );
String output = localDate.format( formatter );
```

You can also parse with that formatter.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2015.09.30" , formatter );
```